# Play framework logging all RuntimeException in futures

Tags: scala, exception, playframework-2.0, log4j, future

I'm creating application in Play Framework 2.2 using Scala, and I want to save in my log files all RuntimeException.

When I add to code something like:

`future.map { f =>
    throw new NullPointerException("bad things happen")
 }`

I have any info in my logs. How should I configure my log4j, and why such behavior is by default?

=== Update

I can catch this exception inside, but maybe there is some better way of catching it outside:

`future.map { f =>
    try {
       ...
       throw new NullPointerException("bad things happen")
    } catch {
      case e:RuntimeException =>
      ...
    }
 }`

Comment: Just to be clear: you are looking for a way to configure log4j to log all occurring RuntimeExceptions without calling log4j at all from your code?

Comment: Yes, but inside Scala Futures, when I have RuntimeException outside Future in normal thread I'm getting such error also in console.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `try-catch` you can call `recover` method of the `future` and print stack trace there:

```
future.map { f =>
    throw new NullPointerException("bad things happen")
}.recover { case ex => ex.printStackTrace() }
```